# .dSYM file missing in VSTS build

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-devops, dsym

I am building the Xamarin ios app on VSTS. I see that its generating .dSYM file during the build time but when I check the artifact folder, I could see ipa file but not dSYM file.

I need dSYM file to run Xamarin Test Cloud.

Am I looking at wrong place or do I need to do something different to get .dSYM file ?

Comment: Which build definition are you using?

Comment: I am using VSTS and running on MacInCloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When building iOS apps from visual studio, the .dSYM file that can be used to symbolicate crash reports ends up on the build host at path:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/<appname>/<guid>/bin/iPhone/<configuration>
```

https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1969488--where-can-i-find-the-dsym-file-to-symbolicate-ios-crash-logs-

Comment: so should i upload the dSYM file into github? I though we need to get the latest dSYM file each and every time build.

Comment: @AzharAli Not sure want you mean by uploading it to github (do you store the `ipa` in a private repo?), you do upload the latest dSYM to test cloud when performing tests, in the cmd line there is the `--dsym=$DSYM` parameter the specific the file.

Comment: I do not store ipa, I get ipa file each and everytime I build it on VSTS via MacInCloud agent. Similarly, to give the location for dSYM file for test cloud is there any way I can point the VSTS to get it from the latest build ??

Comment: @AzharAli I just use a copy task to `scp` it from the Mac to the windows server